# NUMIN producing wrong output,how to get right answer?

Tags: tandem, tal

**I am creating a program to count number of digits in number**

When I am putting value in 5 digits it is producing right answer but when I put value in 6 digits it is producing wrong value.

To see what happening in the code I debugged the code and found that when I put 5 digit number,it convert from string to int correctly but when I put 6 digit value it convert the value wrong and give some negetive value.

I am using

`CALL NUMIN(AB,NUM,10,STAT);`

AB is a string ab[0:40]

NUM is an Integer

STAT is a string STAT[0:50]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TAL the Unsigned Integer ranges from **0 to 65,535** and Signed Integer ranges from **-32,768 to 32,767** , so it is not possible to get 6 digit input in to the string and convert it using NUMIN GPC(Guardian procedure call).

Instead you can use signed double word integer INT(32) .EXT which is 32-bit integer in range **-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647** in which you can easily use 6 digit or more than 6 digit inputs .
To convert 6 character or more than 6 character string to Integer use DNUMIN GPC

```
DNUMIN ( ascii-num 
        ,signed-result
        ,base
        ,status );
```